# TypeScript generic function with inferred return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How do I type a function that has a generic argument, then can return any type, and get the return type of the function to be inferred from usage?

I tried this:

```
type Thing<T> = <U>(value: T) => U

const shouldMakeStrings: Thing<string> = (a: string) => a + 'foo'
const shouldMakeObjects: Thing<string> = (a: string) => ({ foo: a })
```

My expectation was that the type of `shouldMakeStrings` would be `(a: string) => string` and `shouldMakeObjects` would be `(a: string) => { foo: string }`

Instead they error because `'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'`

How can I define the `Thing` type without defining U, but also telling it that I want to allow any return type?

---

Here's a more complete example of what I'm trying to do ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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)):

```typescript
type Thing<T> = <U>(value: T) => U

// Example, this will be a big map of custom types and string representations
type Types = {
  'string': string,
  'number': number
}

type CallbackMap = {
  [P in keyof Types]?: Thing<Types[P]>
}

const callbacks: CallbackMap = {}

const addCallback = <V>(type: keyof Types, callback: Thing<V>) => {
  callbacks[type] = callback
}

addCallback('string', (a: string) => a + 'foo')
addCallback('number', (a: number) => { foo: a })

callbacks.string // = callback that takes a string and returns something, with it's type inferred as string from `addCallback('string')` above
callbacks.number // = callback that takes a number and returns something, with it's type inferred as '{ foo: number }' from `addCallback('number')` above
```

---

Here's a more verbose example, but it has other TypeScript issues ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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)):

```typescript
type A = { foo: string }
type B = { bar: string }
type C = number[]

type Modifiable = {
  'typeA': A,
  'typeB': B,
  'typeC': C
}

type Modifier<T> = <U>(value: T) => U
type ModifierMap = {
  [P in keyof Modifiable]?: Modifier<Modifiable[P]>
}

const modifiers: ModifierMap = {
  'typeA': (a: A) => a
}

const setModifier = <V extends keyof Modifiable = keyof Modifiable>(type: V, callback: Modifier<Modifiable[V]>) => {
  modifiers[type] = callback
}

setModifier('typeA', (input: A) => input.foo + 'a')

setModifier('typeA', a => a.foo)

// With the aim to be able to do something like this:
const makeModifiedA = (modifiers?: ModifierMap) => {
  const a = { foo: "hello world" }

  return modifiers?.typeA ? modifiers.typeA(a) : a
}

makeModifiedA(modifiers) // = "hello world"
setModifier('typeA', (input: A) => ({ ...input, upperFoo: input.foo.toUpperCase() }))
makeModifiedA(modifiers) // = { foo: "hello world", upperFoo: "HELLO WORLD" }
```

Comment: The simplest way would be not to have `Thing` at all: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBAWICuAbAJgWQIYGsCmAylAE4CWYA5hDALwwAUWAXHCeRQJS0B8MWMAahgByAGYgQwgNwBYAFAB6BTBUwAegH55oSLATJ02fAHkARgCs8wKNTqMW0MpS41e9AN4xxIFvwC+HLKKyqqaQA). What's the `Thing` type for?

Comment: I want to be able to store `Thing`s in a map that can be referred to later, to modify objects matching their T type. [Here's a Playground that hopefully makes sense](https://shorturl.at/cUY29)

Comment: [Here's a slightly more verbose playground](https://shorturl.at/cksy1) that's closer to what I'm actually trying to do if that helps, but it has other TypeScript issues in it so I was just focusing on them one at a time

Comment: Both of those links appear to be broken. Your best bet for playground shortlinks is https://tsplay.dev/. It has the advantage of **only** linking to the TypeScript playground.

Comment: Agh thanks, wouldn't allow the full links - Can't edit the comments either so [first one](https://tsplay.dev/mLqjvW), [second one](https://tsplay.dev/wOGglw)

Comment: Looking at your [more complete example](https://tsplay.dev/mLqjvW), I'm afraid I'm 99.99% sure you can't do that (but beware I'm only mid-level with TypeScript so far). With `type CallbackMap = { [P in keyof Types]?: Thing<Types[P]> }`, the type of `callbacks.x` will always be `Thing<string> | undefined` for the property `string` and `Thing<number> | undefined` for the property `number`, whether the functions you're providing to `addCallback` do that or not (which is why `addCallback` has errors). I don't think there's any definition of `callbacks` that would allow `addCallback` to ...

Comment: ... add callbacks with completely novel return values, not least because runtime calls to a function that mutates `callbacks` will not be reflected in the type information for `callbacks`. You can, of course, define an object literal with functions in it that have their types inferred ([example](https://tsplay.dev/w1PXkW)), but my guess is you don't want to do that, you want it to be dynamic at runtime. The "at runtime" part of that is the problem. :-) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript, either you assign a type or you have it inferred. You can't have both.

One thing you could do is writing a hack to check that a function "satisfies" a constraint without "erasing" its type. Its type would then still be inferred but first it would undergo a constraint check.

```js
const satisfies = <Constraint>() => <Input extends Constraint>(input: Input) => input;

const checked = satisfies<(arg: string) => any>()(arg1 => {
  console.log(arg1);
  return 2;
});
```

There is actually a related proposal in progress to add this as a language feature soon, the `satisfies` operator.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920

So in future TS 4.9+ you'd write something like:

```
const checked = ((arg1: string) => 2) satisfies (arg: string) => any
```

Comment: you were faster than me on fixing the 3.9 :D

Answer (score -1):

Would `any`/`unknown` be a match ??

```
type Thing<T> = (value: T) => unknown

const shouldMakeStrings: Thing<string> = (a: string) => a + 'foo'
const shouldMakeObjects: Thing<string> = (a: string) => ({ foo: a })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMA8MB8UC8UAUAbgIYA2ArhAFywCUu25SA1kgPYDuSAsAFB8BjNkgDOwKCLhtypACYBZYswgBlYACdkKETXha0Yzamx58xGoa30c2YlADUUAOQAzNmyeDhYiVJkKlCAB5ACMAKwgBYB1YRFQDDS0TAnMJRNRrbHwAbyg3Nho7AF9aIA)

Comment: The OP said they want to have the return type inferred (*"...with inferred return type..."*, *"...How can I define the `Thing` type without defining `U`..."*).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, sorry

Comment: Not trying to harp. :-) But the update doesn't infer the return type either. (I'm not sure you *can* infer the return type with the `Thing` type, but my TypeScript-fu isn't strong enough to assert that.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If then, you're comment should be the accepted answer ;).  No offence taken =)